# can someone help me how to solve this problem relating a picture slide show?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

i don't know if the problem lays in the fact that I was putting the script in the html file anyways somehow the slide show isn't working  and I would ask if someone can please help me solving this problem the code is below.
somehow the slideshow isn't working but the pictures are show in live server

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="color:black">
    <a href='https://postimg.cc/ZWcwYbzT' target='_blank'><img id="image" src='https://i.postimg.cc/ZWcwYbzT/172374980-914208975812746-8979130836703230386-n.jpg' border='0' width="100" alt='172374980-914208975812746-8979130836703230386-n'/></a>
    <a href='https://postimg.cc/QV9dZVZr' target='_blank'><img id="image1" src='https://i.postimg.cc/QV9dZVZr/172124635-284285833185228-6477325913542767940-n.jpg' border='0' width="100" alt='172124635-284285833185228-6477325913542767940-n'/></a>

    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Start Slide Show" onClick="startSlideShow()">
    <input type="button" value="Stop Slide Show" onClick="stopSlideShow()">
    <script>

   <input type="button" value="Start Slide Show" onClick="startSlideShow()">
    <input type="button" value="Stop Slide Show" onClick="stopSlideShow()">
    <script>
      var intervalID;
  
      function startSlideShow(){
          intervalID = setInterval(changeImage, 800); 
      }
  
      function stopSlideShow(){
          clearInterval(intervalID);  
      }
  
      function changeImage(){
          var imageSrc = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src");
          var currentImageNumber = imageSrc.substring(imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, imageSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 2);
          if(currentImageNumber == 7){
              currentImageNumber = 0;
          }
  
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = currentImageNumber;
          document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src",  "images/" + (Number(currentImageNumber)+1) + ".jpg");     
  
      }
      changeImage();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What **is** the problem?

Comment: "somehow it isn't working" isn't a good problem description.  What behavior are you expecting, and what is it actually doing?  Are you getting errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this part:

```html
   <input type="button" value="Start Slide Show" onClick="startSlideShow()">
    <input type="button" value="Stop Slide Show" onClick="stopSlideShow()">
    <script>
```

appears twice in a row in your code. So you have HTML tags inside your script, and that gives a syntax error. Remove the second occurrence, and you'll be fine.